# Can an ESB imitate a database stored proc and pass the request on to a web service instead?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, esb, mule, spring-integration

I've got an older system that can call a stored proc, but can't call a web service.  The business logic from this stored proc is being migrated into a web service.  Are there any ESB adapters that can simulate a database and accept input in the form of stored proc input variables, then turn around and call a web service?  After the web service returns a result, the answer would need to be  mapped into a result set and/or output variables and sent back to the client.  I would prefer to use Spring Integration or Mule or some other Java-based ESB, but would be willing to consider other options.

Comment: Is this older system calling the stored proc over JDBC?

Comment: You would have to find an ESB that can pretend it is a database to your application.

Comment: As the previous comments hint, the first task is managing your application configuration to use the new module. If your app uses JDBC, maybe it is easier to just write a wrapper for it an intercept all calls to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If the legacy application uses JDBC, use the [**p6spy**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/) driver to intercept the calls and redirect them to the web service.